# How to add multiple select statement one bcp command in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have a bcp command to create a file with columns and headers. I need to add timestamp at the top of the file and Ctrl C at the end. How do I achieve this?

This works fine with queries having union all.

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(5000) ='select ''Col1'', ''Col2'', ''Col3'' union all select col1, col2, col3 from TestTable ' 
DECLARE @cmd1 VARCHAR(5000)='bcp "' + @Query +'" queryout "' +  @File + '" -c -T'
```

I tried to put them in multiple queries and concatenate them to one query

This is what I tried

```
DECLARE @Query1 VARCHAR(5000)='Select Getdate();'
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @Query2 VARCHAR(5000) ='select ''Col1'', ''Col2'', ''Col3'' union all select col1, col2, col3 from TestTable '
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(5000)=@Query1 + @NewLineChar + @Query2 
DECLARE @cmd1 VARCHAR(5000)='bcp "' + @Query +'" queryout "' +  @File + '" -c -T'
```

The output file should be like this

```
12/14/18 17:10

Col1 Col2 Col3
1      2   3  
4      5   6
^C
```

Comment: this cant be done with just bcp.  you'll need to create separate files and combine them together.

Comment: Thanks , will try that.

Comment: how to combine separate files to one ? should I use copy command ? can you provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way will be create a view with header and data (unionall) and query the view in your BCP

Comment: that is already done in Query 2 , I need to add timestamp also

Comment: SELECT  getdate((),'',''  UNION ALL  SELECT  ''col1'', ''col2'',...  UNION ALL  SELECT col1,col2,col3 fro table

and bcp everything to csv file

Comment: union all will work only if all the queries have same number of columns. which is possible by inserting spaces after getdate. I am trying to find out if there is any other way of doing this. Thanks!